# Replace data in a MAP CHART using python pptx

Tags: python-pptx

i am trying to replace the data of an existant map chart using python pptx.

I can replace pie and bar chart with no issues but when i try to apply the same method to a map chart nothing change in the presentation and python give me no errors.

I am trying running this script but the map chart in the slide is not changing at all and python gives me no erros:

```
import pandas as pd
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData

# Load CSV data
data = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

# Initialize PowerPoint presentation from template
prs = Presentation('TEMPLATE_TEST.pptx')

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    slide = prs.slides[row['ID_SLIDE']]
    for num in range(1,20):
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            print(shape.name)
            if shape.name == str(num):    
                if shape.has_text_frame:
                    text_frame = shape.text_frame
                    for paragraph in text_frame.paragraphs:
                        for run in paragraph.runs:
                            run.text = run.text = row[str(num)]
                if (shape.name == str(num)) and ('CHART' in str(shape.shape_type)):
                    risultato_stringa = row[str(num)]
                    risultato_finale = risultato_stringa.split('|')
                    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
                    if len(risultato_finale) == 2:
                        chart_data.categories = ['Target', 'Altro']
                    if len(risultato_finale) == 5:
                        chart_data.categories = ['<35 anni', '35-55 anni', '55-70 anni', '>70 anni', 'NON SPECIF.']
                    chart_data.add_series('VARIABILE', risultato_finale)
                    shape.chart.replace_data(chart_data)
```